# Use set-itemproperty to set a decimal value not hex

Tags: powershell, registry

I need to change two registry values to a value of 30, but they need to be decimal, I'm using the below but it's always writing in hex. I've spent hours googling and playing around trying to find a way to specify the base as decimal not hex - for some reason the Windows 10 VPN timeout can only read decimal time...

```
$val1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP -Name "MaxConfigure"
if($val1.MaxConfigure -ne 30)
{
 set-itemproperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP -Name "MaxConfigure" -value 30
}

$val2 = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP -Name "MaxFailure"
if($val2.MaxFailure -ne 30)
{
 set-itemproperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP -Name "MaxFailure" -value 30
}
```

After running the above both the values are set to Hex 1e, which is 30, but I need the registry entry to have base decimal specified and the value to read as 30

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, `1e` (hex) and `30` (dec) are exactly the same value. What you see in the registry editor is just a display option. Both are actually a `REG_DWORD` value of `0x0000001e`.

You can verify this easily:

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP).MaxFailure
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP).MaxFailure.GetType()
```